# Tkinter MessageBox gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In a GUI program written in Python 3.5 I use the Tkinter module. I define a function to call the MessageBox as follows:

```
def callAbout():
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "About", message = "My Window")
```

When I try to execute, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [PATH]
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tk-error.py", line 4, in callAbout
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "About", message = "My Window")
NameError: name 'messagebox' is not defined
```

It seems that the program cannot find

```
messagebox
```

but I wonder why, since I imported the whole module with

```
from tkinter import *
```

Please, ask if you need the complete code. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Added: Here follows the whole code.

```
from tkinter import *

def callAbout():
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "About", message = "My Window")

win = Tk()

win.geometry('300x300')
win.title("My First Window")

bar_menu = Menu(win)

menu_about = Menu(bar_menu, tearoff = 0)
bar_menu.add_cascade(label = "About", menu = menu_about)
menu_about.add_command(label = "About", command = callAbout)

win.config(menu = bar_menu)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, we'd probably need to see a minimized version of the code...

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3? If you're on Python 2, you'll need to `import tkMessageBox`

Comment: @moogle: yeah, sure I'm on Pyhton 3... Precisely Python 3.5, as above mentioned.

Comment: Hi @EM90 first message: the code runs fine here (but a typo in the code: `win.config(menu = barra_menu)` - should be `bar`) How do you exactly call the window (and on what os)?

Comment: Yeah, the typo comes from the fact that I copy-pasted the code and then changed (almost) everywhere the Italian word "barra" with "bar". Bad habit, I know.
Well, actually, my PC runs the code and creates the window, but, when it comes to clicking on the button About in the menu, it gives the error... 
Maybe it can be of some use to know the fact that I'm running on Windows 10 Home?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. I am running it on Ubuntu 16.04. Will try it on Windows 10 though...

Comment: Hi @EM90 on windows, I get the same error like you...

Comment: Then it may be a matter of operating system...!

Comment: Yeah, obviously, the modules are differently arranged on Windows and Linux.

Comment: `messagebox` is not imported when you do `from tkinter import *`.  You have to explicitly import it.

Comment: @BryanOakley ^ not on Linux, it works fine here (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: When you import modules by wildcard, like in `from tkinter import *` you don't import the packages of the module. A package is just like a directory with additional modules. To import all of the methods of a package you have to write `from module.package import *`. Its like the dir command of Windows. `DIR C:\WINDOWS\*` gives you all files in C;\WINDOWS but not the files in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32. To see them you have to type `DIR C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\*`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `messagebox.showinfo` to `showinfo` and add `from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


def callAbout():
    showinfo(title="About", message="My Window")


win = Tk()

win.geometry('300x300')
win.title("My First Window")

bar_menu = Menu(win)

menu_about = Menu(bar_menu, tearoff=0)
bar_menu.add_cascade(label="About", menu=menu_about)
menu_about.add_command(label="About", command=callAbout)

win.config(menu=bar_menu)

win.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok, your answer actually works. 
But I'd like to know the very reason of the "import" command behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You can import and use the *messagebox* module by using an alias:

```
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
```

Here is your code after making changes,

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

def callAbout():
    tkmb.showinfo(title = "About", message = "My Window")

win = tk.Tk()

win.geometry('300x300')
win.title("My First Window")

bar_menu = tk.Menu(win)

menu_about = tk.Menu(bar_menu, tearoff = 0)
bar_menu.add_cascade(label = "About", menu = menu_about)
menu_about.add_command(label = "About", command = callAbout)

win.config(menu = bar_menu)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I changed the code like this. simply...

---

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox
```

---

Answer (score 0):

messagebox, along with some other modules like filedialog, does not automatically get imported when you import tkinter. Import it explicitly, using as and/or from as desired. check below 3 examples for better clarification-

```
    >>> import tkinter
    >>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'
```

.

```
    >>> import tkinter.messagebox
    >>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

'ok'
```

.

```
 >>> from tkinter import messagebox
    >>> messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

'ok'
```